# Convert date to epoch format within a file for multiple entries using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

below is the format in a file. can anyone help in converting first two columns which is in date format to epoch format?

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702058496,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702058496,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702058496,3,332,0,0,0,332,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702058496,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702062592,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702062592,2,0,0,0,0,919,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702062592,3,919,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702062592,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702066688,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702066688,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702066688,3,0,0,0,0,919,0,0

2018-01-02 05:44:00,2018-01-02 05:59:00,1,702066688,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 10:44:00,2018-01-02 10:59:00,1,702058496,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

2018-01-02 10:44:00,2018-01-02 10:59:00,1,702058496,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

i tried with following command.

aa=`cat ATMIF.180102-0615 |grep -|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`; for i in `cat ATMIF.180102-0615 |grep -|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'` ;do date -d "$aa" "+%s"; done

but it is giving error as:
date: invalid date `2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00'
date: invalid date`2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00'
date: invalid date `2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 05:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00\n2018-01-02 10:44:00'

Comment: i tried with following command.
aa=`cat ATMIF.180102-0615 |grep -|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`; for i in `cat ATMIF.180102-0615 |grep -|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'` ;do date -d "$aa" "+%s"; done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it, assuming data are in :

```
IFS=,;while read line; do 
  ff=($line); 
  ff[0]=`date -d "${ff[0]}" +%s`;
  ff[1]=`date -d "${ff[1]}" +%s`;
  echo "${ff[*]}"; 
done < file.in > file.out
```

Note: you may need to add 'UTC' in date command according to origin format.

Now to do it in-place as asked by your comment, you need to loop on all files. For example using find command to match all .csv files recursively in /mypath/to-files/:

```
for file in $(find /mypath/to-files -name "*.csv"); do
  cp $file /tmp/tmp.csv
  IFS=,;while read line; do 
      ff=($line); 
      ff[0]=`date -d "${ff[0]}" +%s`;
      ff[1]=`date -d "${ff[1]}" +%s`;
      echo "${ff[*]}"; 
    done < /tmp/tmp.csv > $file
done
```

Comment: Hello Tonic,
Thanks Much.. this is working fine. but i'm trying to replace converted date in same file instead of redirecting to new one, as like this file i have many files to be converted for which i'm doing as below

IFS=,;i=1
read fn
echo $fn
while read line; do

ff=($line);
if [ $i -gt 1 ];then

  ff[0]=`date -d "${ff[0]}" +%s`;
  ff[1]=`date -d "${ff[1]}" +%s`;
fi
  echo "${ff[*]}";
((i=i+1))
done < $fn > tempfile
cat tempfile > /tmp/MODIFIED/$fn
rm $fn
which would create a new file in different path.